# How to pause/start GSAP animation in onClick event Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, gsap

I want to pause/start animation using GSAP in Nextjs. I can't find a way to work with a tl.current outside the useEffect hook. This in this component when I click on the first .imgWrapper I want the tl.current to toggle tl.current.paused(true) and pause the animation. But no way I can make it work

```js
export const Projects = () => {
  const projects = useRef();
  const projectTitle = useRef(null);
  const tl = useRef();
  const q = gsap.utils.selector(projects);

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(2)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        paused: false,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(2)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        paused: false,
      });
    tl.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(3)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 1,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(3)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 1,
      });
    tl.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(4)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 2,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(4)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 2,
      });
   
  }, []);
  const [animate_1, setAnimate_1] = useState(false);
  const [animate_2, setAnimate_2] = useState(false);
  const [animate_3, setAnimate_3] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section
      ref={projects}
      id="projects"
      className={`${animate_1 && "animated_1"} ${animate_2 && "animated_2"} ${
        animate_3 && "animated_3"
      }
       w_100 h_100vh flex flexColumn flexAlignCenter flexCenter p4em`}
    >
      <div className="projectsLoading flex flexCenter flexAlignCenter w_100 h_100">
        <h2>LOADING PROJECTS</h2>
      </div>
      <div className={`singleProject w_100 flex flexStart`}>
        <div className="imgWrapper" onClick={() => some code}>
          <img src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/lego.jpg"} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="singleProject w_100 flex flexEnd">
        <div className="imgWrapper">
          <img
            onClick={() => {
              setAnimate_2(!animate_2);
            }}
            src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/jordan.png"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="singleProject w_100 flex flexStart">
        <div className="imgWrapper">
          <img
            onClick={() => setAnimate_3(!animate_3)}
            src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/ferrari.png"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

This is what is showing up in the console when I colsole.log(tl.current.pause())

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo0LR.png

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried using `tl.current.pause()` to pause the timeline animation?

Comment: Yes and nothing happens at all. I logged it to the console and a timeline object shows up only. I have added the console results to the question above. Thanks, @juliomalves in advance.

Comment: Tried replicating your issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sound-kj00y?file=/pages/index.js) and using `tl.current.pause()` seems to work for me. Clicking on the image that's animating pauses its animation.

Comment: Hello, @juliomalves, and thanks for responding. I think I know where is my problem now! I have shortened the code in my question. My whole code has multiple timelines in the useEffect hook. They are the same as the timeline I provided in my code but with different selectors pointing to each of the .singleProject classes. It seems to be working with only one timeline but when I duplicate them it breaks. I will need to find a solution to this one now. And I will update my question again. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using different `ref`s for each timeline?

Comment: I will try and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried today different refs and it's working perfectly. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated answer to the question.

```js
export const Projects = () => {
  const projects = useRef();
  const projectTitle = useRef(null);
  const tl = useRef();
  const first = useRef();
  const second = useRef();
  const third = useRef();
  const q = gsap.utils.selector(projects);

  useEffect(() => {
    first.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(2)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        paused: false,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(2)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        paused: false,
      });

    second.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(3)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 1,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(3)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 1,
      });
    third.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from(q(".singleProject:nth-child(4)"), {
        y: 2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 2,
      })
      .to(q(".singleProject:nth-child(4)"), {
        y: -2000,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 20,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 2,
      });
  }, []);
  const [animate_1, setAnimate_1] = useState(false);
  const [animate_2, setAnimate_2] = useState(false);
  const [animate_3, setAnimate_3] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section
      ref={projects}
      id="projects"
      className={`${animate_1 && "animated_1"} ${animate_2 && "animated_2"} ${
        animate_3 && "animated_3"
      }
       w_100 h_100vh flex flexColumn flexAlignCenter flexCenter p4em`}
    >
      <div className="projectsLoading flex flexCenter flexAlignCenter w_100 h_100">
        <h2>LOADING PROJECTS</h2>
      </div>
      <div ref={first} className={`singleProject w_100 flex flexStart`}>
        <div
          className="imgWrapper"
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            first.current.paused(true);
            second.current.paused(true);
            third.current.paused(true);
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            first.current.paused(false);
            second.current.paused(false);
            third.current.paused(false);
          }}
        >
          <img src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/lego.jpg"} />
        </div>
        {/* <div className="projectDetails flex flexColumn flexAlignStart flexCenter">
          <h2 ref={projectTitle}>PROJECT TITLE</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem,
            veniam! Reiciendis, totam explicabo quisquam dolorem quibusdam sit
            dignissimos corporis veniam.
          </p>
        </div> */}
      </div>
      <div ref={second} className="singleProject w_100 flex flexEnd">
        <div className="imgWrapper">
          <img
            onMouseEnter={() => {
              first.current.paused(true);
              second.current.paused(true);
              third.current.paused(true);
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              first.current.paused(false);
              second.current.paused(false);
              third.current.paused(false);
            }}
            src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/jordan.png"}
          />
        </div>

        {/* <div className="projectDetails flex flexColumn flexAlignStart flexCenter">
          <h2 ref={projectTitle}>PROJECT TITLE</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem,
            veniam! Reiciendis, totam explicabo quisquam dolorem quibusdam sit
            dignissimos corporis veniam.
          </p>
        </div> */}
      </div>
      <div ref={third} className="singleProject w_100 flex flexStart">
        <div className="imgWrapper">
          <img
            onMouseEnter={() => {
              first.current.paused(true);
              second.current.paused(true);
              third.current.paused(true);
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              first.current.paused(false);
              second.current.paused(false);
              third.current.paused(false);
            }}
            src={"https://www.aimanalmureish.com/img/ferrari.png"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```